# see this jvm crash, I use NIO to read and write files, it happens during read, but not always what's wrong

Tags: java, jvm, nio, jvm-crash

it not always happen , we can‘t restore the situation stability. we thought it was a mutithread error  and add synchronized , but it seems not works, what can I do?

here is the get method:

```
public synchronized T get(long pos){
    initBuffer(pos);
    return getValue((int) (pos & getPageModeValue()));
}
```

initBuffer is used to init the buffer file and create read buffer, if the buffer is the right buffer do nothing,  getValue just use the buffer to read from direct postion from file

here is the crash report:

```
 #
    #
    #  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000002cecdb0, pid=4084, tid=3256
    #
    # JRE version: 7.0_09-b05
    # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.5-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
    # Problematic frame:
    # J  com.fr.bi.cube.engine.newio.read.AbstractNIOReader.get(J)Ljava/lang/Object;
    #
    # Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
    #
    #

    ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

    Current thread (0x000000001be65800):  JavaThread "SocketListener0-1" [_thread_in_Java, id=3256, stack(0x0000000023280000,0x0000000023380000)]

    siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000029e45d4c

    Registers:
    RAX=0x0000000000015d4c, RBX=0x000000002337e3d0, RCX=0x0000000000000016, RDX=0x0000000607009060
    RSP=0x000000002337e370, RBP=0x00000000c0dbfa9f, RSI=0x0000000000015d4c, RDI=0x0000000781d822e8
    R8 =0x0000000000015d4c, R9 =0x0000000000015d4c, R10=0x0000000029e30000, R11=0x0000000000015d4c
    R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x000000002337e490, R14=0x00000005fdfbac60, R15=0x000000001be65800
    RIP=0x0000000002cecdb0, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010283

    Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000002337e370)
    0x000000002337e370:   00000000f03b0075 0000000002d63e68
    0x000000002337e380:   0000001500000001 0000000781d81140
    0x000000002337e390:   000000070000000e 0000000000015d4c
    0x000000002337e3a0:   0000000700000000 0000000607009060
    0x000000002337e3b0:   0000000781d803a8 0000000781d810a8
    0x000000002337e3c0:   00000000f03b005d 0000000002d82824
    0x000000002337e3d0:   0000000000000021 00000000001f5e03
    0x000000002337e3e0:   000000002337e4e0 0000000002ca3c38
    0x000000002337e3f0:   00000005fdf09e50 000000002337e438
    0x000000002337e400:   00000005fdf0a8c0 00000005fdf3a648
    0x000000002337e410:   0000000607009040 0000000000000014
    0x000000002337e420:   0000000000015d4c 0000000000001177
    0x000000002337e430:   0000000781d822c0 00000005fdf14e8e
    0x000000002337e440:   000000002337e490 000000002337e448
    0x000000002337e450:   000000002337e4e0 0000000002b3946c
    0x000000002337e460:   00000005fdf12b30 00000005fdf3a6f0 

    Instructions: (pc=0x0000000002cecdb0)
    0x0000000002cecd90:   20 45 8b 54 ec 1c 45 85 c9 0f 8c 6a 03 00 00 45
    0x0000000002cecda0:   3b ca 0f 8d 61 03 00 00 4d 8b 54 ec 10 4d 63 d9
    0x0000000002cecdb0:   4f 0f be 14 1a 49 bb c8 1e 2a 03 06 00 00 00 47
    0x0000000002cecdc0:   8b 9c 93 10 02 00 00 49 8b db 48 c1 e3 03 41 ba 


    Register to memory mapping:

    RAX=0x0000000000015d4c is an unknown value
    RBX=0x000000002337e3d0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001be65800
    RCX=0x0000000000000016 is an unknown value
    RDX=0x0000000607009060 is an oop
    com.fr.bi.cube.engine.newio.read.ByteNIOReader 
     - klass: 'com/fr/bi/cube/engine/newio/read/ByteNIOReader'
    RSP=0x000000002337e370 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001be65800
    RBP=0x00000000c0dbfa9f is an unknown value
    RSI=0x0000000000015d4c is an unknown value
    RDI=0x0000000781d822e8 is an unknown value
    R8 =0x0000000000015d4c is an unknown value
    R9 =0x0000000000015d4c is an unknown value
    R10=0x0000000029e30000 is an unknown value
    R11=0x0000000000015d4c is an unknown value
    R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
    R13=0x000000002337e490 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001be65800
    R14=0x00000005fdfbac60 is an oop
    {method data} 
     - klass: {other class}
    R15=0x000000001be65800 is a thread


    Stack: [0x0000000023280000,0x0000000023380000],  sp=0x000000002337e370,  free space=1016k
    Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
    J  com.fr.bi.cube.engine.newio.read.AbstractNIOReader.get(J)Ljava/lang/Object;


    ---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

    Java Threads: ( => current thread )
      0x00000000200ec000 JavaThread "SocketListener0-12" [_thread_in_native, id=4188, stack(0x0000000027590000,0x0000000027690000)]
      0x00000000200ea800 JavaThread "SocketListener0-10" [_thread_in_native, id=2692, stack(0x00000000272e0000,0x00000000273e0000)]
      0x00000000200ea000 JavaThread "SocketListener0-9" [_thread_in_native, id=2540, stack(0x0000000027120000,0x0000000027220000)]
      0x000000001e5c5800 JavaThread "SocketListener0-8" [_thread_blocked, id=1988, stack(0x0000000026c30000,0x0000000026d30000)]
      0x000000001e5c5000 JavaThread "SocketListener0-7" [_thread_in_native, id=2396, stack(0x0000000026f40000,0x0000000027040000)]
      0x000000001e5c4000 JavaThread "SocketListener0-6" [_thread_blocked, id=4572, stack(0x0000000026d70000,0x0000000026e70000)]
      0x000000001f9d7800 JavaThread "Timer-4" [_thread_blocked, id=4504, stack(0x0000000024b40000,0x0000000024c40000)]
      0x000000001e5c3800 JavaThread "Thread-24" [_thread_blocked, id=2592, stack(0x0000000026ad0000,0x0000000026bd0000)]
      0x000000001e5c2800 JavaThread "SocketListener0-5" [_thread_blocked, id=2076, stack(0x0000000026900000,0x0000000026a00000)]
      0x000000001e5c1000 JavaThread "Timer-3" [_thread_blocked, id=4524, stack(0x00000000266b0000,0x00000000267b0000)]
      0x000000001e5c0800 JavaThread "Timer-2" [_thread_blocked, id=532, stack(0x00000000267d0000,0x00000000268d0000)]
      0x000000001e5bf800 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-20" [_thread_blocked, id=3292, stack(0x0000000026270000,0x0000000026370000)]
      0x000000001e5bf000 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-19" [_thread_blocked, id=2456, stack(0x00000000265b0000,0x00000000266b0000)]
      0x000000001fce4800 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-18" [_thread_blocked, id=4292, stack(0x00000000264a0000,0x00000000265a0000)]
      0x000000001fce3800 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-17" [_thread_blocked, id=3600, stack(0x0000000026370000,0x0000000026470000)]
      0x000000001fce3000 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-16" [_thread_blocked, id=4712, stack(0x0000000025610000,0x0000000025710000)]
      0x000000001fce2000 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-15" [_thread_blocked, id=4132, stack(0x0000000026110000,0x0000000026210000)]
      0x000000001fce1800 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-14" [_thread_blocked, id=5024, stack(0x0000000025fd0000,0x00000000260d0000)]
      0x000000001fce0800 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-13" [_thread_blocked, id=2872, stack(0x0000000025e00000,0x0000000025f00000)]
      0x000000001fce0000 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-12" [_thread_blocked, id=4036, stack(0x0000000025bc0000,0x0000000025cc0000)]
      0x000000001fcdf000 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-11" [_thread_blocked, id=3180, stack(0x0000000025a50000,0x0000000025b50000)]
      0x000000001fcde800 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-10" [_thread_blocked, id=1552, stack(0x0000000020b20000,0x0000000020c20000)]
      0x000000001fcdd800 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-9" [_thread_blocked, id=5084, stack(0x0000000025880000,0x0000000025980000)]
      0x000000001f9dd800 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-8" [_thread_blocked, id=5092, stack(0x0000000025740000,0x0000000025840000)]
      0x000000001f9dd000 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-7" [_thread_blocked, id=4512, stack(0x00000000254f0000,0x00000000255f0000)]
      0x000000001f9dc000 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-6" [_thread_blocked, id=1368, stack(0x00000000252e0000,0x00000000253e0000)]
      0x000000001f9db800 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-5" [_thread_blocked, id=3296, stack(0x0000000025150000,0x0000000025250000)]
      0x000000001f9da800 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-4" [_thread_blocked, id=4876, stack(0x0000000024850000,0x0000000024950000)]
      0x000000001f9da000 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-3" [_thread_blocked, id=1764, stack(0x0000000024ff0000,0x00000000250f0000)]
      0x000000001f9d9000 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-2" [_thread_blocked, id=3768, stack(0x0000000024e00000,0x0000000024f00000)]
      0x000000001f9d8800 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=2964, stack(0x0000000024c90000,0x0000000024d90000)]
      0x000000001f9d7000 JavaThread "Timer-1" [_thread_blocked, id=3220, stack(0x0000000024950000,0x0000000024a50000)]
      0x000000001be68000 JavaThread "SocketListener0-3" [_thread_in_native, id=3720, stack(0x0000000023860000,0x0000000023960000)]
      0x000000001be67000 JavaThread "SocketListener0-2" [_thread_in_native, id=2696, stack(0x00000000236a0000,0x00000000237a0000)]
      0x000000001be66800 JavaThread "SessionScavenger" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3728, stack(0x0000000023450000,0x0000000023550000)]
    =>0x000000001be65800 JavaThread "SocketListener0-1" [_thread_in_Java, id=3256, stack(0x0000000023280000,0x0000000023380000)]
      0x000000001be65000 JavaThread "SocketListener0-0" [_thread_in_native, id=4596, stack(0x0000000023040000,0x0000000023140000)]
      0x000000001be64000 JavaThread "Acceptor ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,port=0,localport=8075]" [_thread_in_native, id=2156, stack(0x0000000022f30000,0x0000000023030000)]
      0x000000001be63800 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=2120, stack(0x0000000002880000,0x0000000002980000)]
      0x000000001fafd000 JavaThread "Timer-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2808, stack(0x0000000022d50000,0x0000000022e50000)]
      0x000000001f777000 JavaThread "Swing-Shell" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1976, stack(0x0000000021840000,0x0000000021940000)]
      0x000000001f8b5800 JavaThread "TimerQueue" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3684, stack(0x00000000208c0000,0x00000000209c0000)]
      0x000000001f9cb800 JavaThread "Thread-4" [_thread_in_native, id=2372, stack(0x000000001f110000,0x000000001f210000)]
      0x000000001f9cb000 JavaThread "SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2308, stack(0x0000000020720000,0x0000000020820000)]
      0x000000001e80c000 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_blocked, id=3760, stack(0x000000001f350000,0x000000001f450000)]
      0x000000001df7c800 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4692, stack(0x000000001ef90000,0x000000001f090000)]
      0x000000001dff2000 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=4816, stack(0x000000001e380000,0x000000001e480000)]
      0x000000001df94800 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2800, stack(0x000000001ed60000,0x000000001ee60000)]
      0x000000001be73000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3372, stack(0x000000001d9b0000,0x000000001dab0000)]
      0x000000001be62800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2708, stack(0x000000001d700000,0x000000001d800000)]
      0x000000001be5e000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4224, stack(0x000000001d570000,0x000000001d670000)]
      0x000000001be5c800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=972, stack(0x000000001d3b0000,0x000000001d4b0000)]
      0x000000001be55000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1280, stack(0x000000001d270000,0x000000001d370000)]
      0x0000000001d86000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3612, stack(0x000000001d0c0000,0x000000001d1c0000)]
      0x0000000001d7f000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4396, stack(0x000000001cfa0000,0x000000001d0a0000)]

    Other Threads:
      0x000000001bdb2800 VMThread [stack: 0x000000001ce20000,0x000000001cf20000] [id=3112]
      0x000000001be8b800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x000000001dba0000,0x000000001dca0000] [id=5008]

    VM state:synchronizing (normal execution)

    VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
    [0x000000000264af90] Safepoint_lock - owner thread: 0x000000001bdb2800
    [0x000000000264b010] Threads_lock - owner thread: 0x000000001bdb2800

    Heap
     PSYoungGen      total 1543872K, used 733325K [0x0000000755560000, 0x00000007d0720000, 0x0000000800000000)
      eden space 1543680K, 47% used [0x0000000755560000,0x000000078215e228,0x00000007b38e0000)
      from space 192K, 77% used [0x00000007d06f0000,0x00000007d07151f8,0x00000007d0720000)
      to   space 87744K, 0% used [0x00000007c5bc0000,0x00000007c5bc0000,0x00000007cb170000)
     ParOldGen       total 699072K, used 118573K [0x0000000600000000, 0x000000062aab0000, 0x0000000755560000)
      object space 699072K, 16% used [0x0000000600000000,0x00000006073cb748,0x000000062aab0000)
     PSPermGen       total 51008K, used 50924K [0x00000005fae00000, 0x00000005fdfd0000, 0x0000000600000000)
      object space 51008K, 99% used [0x00000005fae00000,0x00000005fdfbb250,0x00000005fdfd0000)

    Card table byte_map: [0x0000000005980000,0x00000000069b0000] byte_map_base: 0x00000000029a9000

    Polling page: 0x0000000000230000

    Code Cache  [0x0000000002980000, 0x0000000002db0000, 0x0000000005980000)
     total_blobs=2024 nmethods=1320 adapters=654 free_code_cache=44954Kb largest_free_block=45946560

    Compilation events (10 events):
    Event: 50.922 Thread 0x000000001be5e000 1364             com.fr.bi.cube.engine.index.LargeGroupValueIndex::Traversal (201 bytes)
    Event: 50.932 Thread 0x000000001be62800 1365             java.util.HashMap::keySet (28 bytes)
    Event: 50.932 Thread 0x000000001be5e000 nmethod 1364 0x0000000002da6f50 code [0x0000000002da7100, 0x0000000002da7878]
    Event: 50.933 Thread 0x000000001be62800 nmethod 1365 0x0000000002c98310 code [0x0000000002c98460, 0x0000000002c98558]
    Event: 50.935 Thread 0x000000001be5e000 1366   !         java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl::acquireFD (29 bytes)
    Event: 50.936 Thread 0x000000001be5e000 nmethod 1366 0x0000000002da51d0 code [0x0000000002da5300, 0x0000000002da5558]
    Event: 50.937 Thread 0x000000001be62800 1367   !         java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl::releaseFD (74 bytes)
    Event: 50.938 Thread 0x000000001be62800 nmethod 1367 0x0000000002c9df50 code [0x0000000002c9e0a0, 0x0000000002c9e458]
    Event: 51.172 Thread 0x000000001be5e000 1368             com.fr.bi.cube.engine.index.LargeGroupValueIndex::LargeGroupValueIndexHasSameValueLargeGroupValueIndex (250 bytes)
    Event: 51.197 Thread 0x000000001be5e000 nmethod 1368 0x0000000002dac1d0 code [0x0000000002dac460, 0x0000000002dad600]

    GC Heap History (10 events):
    Event: 46.808 GC heap before
    {Heap before GC invocations=7 (full 1):
     PSYoungGen      total 568064K, used 551827K [0x0000000755560000, 0x000000077aac0000, 0x0000000800000000)
      eden space 524416K, 100% used [0x0000000755560000,0x0000000775580000,0x0000000775580000)
      from space 43648K, 62% used [0x0000000775580000,0x0000000777044cc0,0x0000000778020000)
      to   space 43648K, 0% used [0x0000000778020000,0x0000000778020000,0x000000077aac0000)
     ParOldGen       total 699072K, used 92549K [0x0000000600000000, 0x000000062aab0000, 0x0000000755560000)
      object space 699072K, 13% used [0x0000000600000000,0x0000000605a615e0,0x000000062aab0000)
     PSPermGen       total 50816K, used 50814K [0x00000005fae00000, 0x00000005fdfa0000, 0x0000000600000000)
      object space 50816K, 99% used [0x00000005fae00000,0x00000005fdf9fa40,0x00000005fdfa0000)
    Event: 46.832 GC heap after
    Heap after GC invocations=7 (full 1):
     PSYoungGen      total 526976K, used 26255K [0x0000000755560000, 0x000000079fb20000, 0x0000000800000000)
      eden space 483328K, 0% used [0x0000000755560000,0x0000000755560000,0x0000000772d60000)
      from space 43648K, 60% used [0x0000000778020000,0x00000007799c3f10,0x000000077aac0000)
      to   space 84736K, 0% used [0x0000000772d60000,0x0000000772d60000,0x0000000778020000)
     ParOldGen       total 699072K, used 92549K [0x0000000600000000, 0x000000062aab0000, 0x0000000755560000)
      object space 699072K, 13% used [0x0000000600000000,0x0000000605a615e0,0x000000062aab0000)
     PSPermGen       total 50816K, used 50814K [0x00000005fae00000, 0x00000005fdfa0000, 0x0000000600000000)
      object space 50816K, 99% used [0x00000005fae00000,0x00000005fdf9fa40,0x00000005fdfa0000)
    }
    Event: 47.597 GC heap before
    {Heap before GC invocations=8 (full 1):
     PSYoungGen      total 526976K, used 509583K [0x0000000755560000, 0x000000079fb20000, 0x0000000800000000)
      eden space 483328K, 100% used [0x0000000755560000,0x0000000772d60000,0x0000000772d60000)
      from space 43648K, 60% used [0x0000000778020000,0x00000007799c3f10,0x000000077aac0000)
      to   space 84736K, 0% used [0x0000000772d60000,0x0000000772d60000,0x0000000778020000)
     ParOldGen       total 699072K, used 92549K [0x0000000600000000, 0x000000062aab0000, 0x0000000755560000)
      object space 699072K, 13% used [0x0000000600000000,0x0000000605a615e0,0x000000062aab0000)
     PSPermGen       total 51008K, used 50874K [0x00000005fae00000, 0x00000005fdfd0000, 0x0000000600000000)
      object space 51008K, 99% used [0x00000005fae00000,0x00000005fdfae9d0,0x00000005fdfd0000)
    Event: 47.620 GC heap after
    Heap after GC invocations=8 (full 1):
     PSYoungGen      total 568064K, used 26111K [0x0000000755560000, 0x000000079a880000, 0x0000000800000000)
      eden space 483328K, 0% used [0x0000000755560000,0x0000000755560000,0x0000000772d60000)
      from space 84736K, 30% used [0x0000000772d60000,0x00000007746dff20,0x0000000778020000)
      to   space 83520K, 0% used [0x00000007956f0000,0x00000007956f0000,0x000000079a880000)
     ParOldGen       total 699072K, used 92549K [0x0000000600000000, 0x000000062aab0000, 0x0000000755560000)
      object space 699072K, 13% used [0x0000000600000000,0x0000000605a615e0,0x000000062aab0000)
     PSPermGen       total 51008K, used 50874K [0x00000005fae00000, 0x00000005fdfd0000, 0x0000000600000000)
      object space 51008K, 99% used [0x00000005fae00000,0x00000005fdfae9d0,0x00000005fdfd0000)
    }
    Event: 47.906 GC heap before
    {Heap before GC invocations=9 (full 1):
     PSYoungGen      total 568064K, used 509439K [0x0000000755560000, 0x000000079a880000, 0x0000000800000000)
      eden space 483328K, 100% used [0x0000000755560000,0x0000000772d60000,0x0000000772d60000)
      from space 84736K, 30% used [0x0000000772d60000,0x00000007746dff20,0x0000000778020000)
      to   space 83520K, 0% used [0x00000007956f0000,0x00000007956f0000,0x000000079a880000)
     ParOldGen       total 699072K, used 92549K [0x0000000600000000, 0x000000062aab0000, 0x0000000755560000)
      object space 699072K, 13% used [0x0000000600000000,0x0000000605a615e0,0x000000062aab0000)
     PSPermGen       total 51008K, used 50876K [0x00000005fae00000, 0x00000005fdfd0000, 0x0000000600000000)
      object space 51008K, 99% used [0x00000005fae00000,0x00000005fdfaf378,0x00000005fdfd0000)
    Event: 47.951 GC heap after
    Heap after GC invocations=9 (full 1):
     PSYoungGen      total 1048320K, used 8344K [0x0000000755560000, 0x000000079ac20000, 0x0000000800000000)
      eden space 964800K, 0% used [0x0000000755560000,0x0000000755560000,0x0000000790390000)
      from space 83520K, 9% used [0x00000007956f0000,0x0000000795f163e0,0x000000079a880000)
      to   space 85376K, 0% used [0x0000000790390000,0x0000000790390000,0x00000007956f0000)
     ParOldGen       total 699072K, used 110384K [0x0000000600000000, 0x000000062aab0000, 0x0000000755560000)
      object space 699072K, 15% used [0x0000000600000000,0x0000000606bcc250,0x000000062aab0000)
     PSPermGen       total 51008K, used 50876K [0x00000005fae00000, 0x00000005fdfd0000, 0x0000000600000000)
      object space 51008K, 99% used [0x00000005fae00000,0x00000005fdfaf378,0x00000005fdfd0000)
    }
    Event: 48.604 GC heap before
    {Heap before GC invocations=10 (full 1):
     PSYoungGen      total 1048320K, used 973144K [0x0000000755560000, 0x000000079ac20000, 0x0000000800000000)
      eden space 964800K, 100% used [0x0000000755560000,0x0000000790390000,0x0000000790390000)
      from space 83520K, 9% used [0x00000007956f0000,0x0000000795f163e0,0x000000079a880000)
      to   space 85376K, 0% used [0x0000000790390000,0x0000000790390000,0x00000007956f0000)
     ParOldGen       total 699072K, used 110384K [0x0000000600000000, 0x000000062aab0000, 0x0000000755560000)
      object space 699072K, 15% used [0x0000000600000000,0x0000000606bcc250,0x000000062aab0000)
     PSPermGen       total 51008K, used 50877K [0x00000005fae00000, 0x00000005fdfd0000, 0x0000000600000000)
      object space 51008K, 99% used [0x00000005fae00000,0x00000005fdfaf488,0x00000005fdfd0000)
    Event: 48.617 GC heap after
    Heap after GC invocations=10 (full 1):
     PSYoungGen      total 1050176K, used 320K [0x0000000755560000, 0x00000007d5c20000, 0x0000000800000000)
      eden space 964800K, 0% used [0x0000000755560000,0x0000000755560000,0x0000000790390000)
      from space 85376K, 0% used [0x0000000790390000,0x00000007903e0000,0x00000007956f0000)
      to   space 87232K, 0% used [0x00000007d06f0000,0x00000007d06f0000,0x00000007d5c20000)
     ParOldGen       total 699072K, used 118349K [0x0000000600000000, 0x000000062aab0000, 0x0000000755560000)
      object space 699072K, 16% used [0x0000000600000000,0x0000000607393748,0x000000062aab0000)
     PSPermGen       total 51008K, used 50877K [0x00000005fae00000, 0x00000005fdfd0000, 0x0000000600000000)
      object space 51008K, 99% used [0x00000005fae00000,0x00000005fdfaf488,0x00000005fdfd0000)
    }
    Event: 49.181 GC heap before
    {Heap before GC invocations=11 (full 1):
     PSYoungGen      total 1050176K, used 965120K [0x0000000755560000, 0x00000007d5c20000, 0x0000000800000000)
      eden space 964800K, 100% used [0x0000000755560000,0x0000000790390000,0x0000000790390000)
      from space 85376K, 0% used [0x0000000790390000,0x00000007903e0000,0x00000007956f0000)
      to   space 87232K, 0% used [0x00000007d06f0000,0x00000007d06f0000,0x00000007d5c20000)
     ParOldGen       total 699072K, used 118349K [0x0000000600000000, 0x000000062aab0000, 0x0000000755560000)
      object space 699072K, 16% used [0x0000000600000000,0x0000000607393748,0x000000062aab0000)
     PSPermGen       total 51008K, used 50877K [0x00000005fae00000, 0x00000005fdfd0000, 0x0000000600000000)
      object space 51008K, 99% used [0x00000005fae00000,0x00000005fdfaf708,0x00000005fdfd0000)
    Event: 49.184 GC heap after
    Heap after GC invocations=11 (full 1):
     PSYoungGen      total 1543872K, used 148K [0x0000000755560000, 0x00000007d0720000, 0x0000000800000000)
      eden space 1543680K, 0% used [0x0000000755560000,0x0000000755560000,0x00000007b38e0000)
      from space 192K, 77% used [0x00000007d06f0000,0x00000007d07151f8,0x00000007d0720000)
      to   space 87744K, 0% used [0x00000007c5bc0000,0x00000007c5bc0000,0x00000007cb170000)
     ParOldGen       total 699072K, used 118573K [0x0000000600000000, 0x000000062aab0000, 0x0000000755560000)
      object space 699072K, 16% used [0x0000000600000000,0x00000006073cb748,0x000000062aab0000)
     PSPermGen       total 51008K, used 50877K [0x00000005fae00000, 0x00000005fdfd0000, 0x0000000600000000)
      object space 51008K, 99% used [0x00000005fae00000,0x00000005fdfaf708,0x00000005fdfd0000)
    }

    Deoptimization events (10 events):
    Event: 49.267 Thread 0x000000001fce0800 Uncommon trap -83 fr.pc 0x0000000002d5c060
    Event: 49.269 Thread 0x000000001fce0800 Uncommon trap -34 fr.pc 0x0000000002cf11f8
    Event: 49.269 Thread 0x000000001fce0800 Uncommon trap -34 fr.pc 0x0000000002cf11f8
    Event: 49.269 Thread 0x000000001fce0800 Uncommon trap -34 fr.pc 0x0000000002cf11f8
    Event: 49.270 Thread 0x000000001fce0800 Uncommon trap -34 fr.pc 0x0000000002cf11f8
    Event: 49.273 Thread 0x000000001fce0800 Uncommon trap -83 fr.pc 0x0000000002c0db14
    Event: 50.918 Thread 0x000000001be65800 Uncommon trap -34 fr.pc 0x0000000002c24634
    Event: 50.923 Thread 0x000000001be65800 Uncommon trap -34 fr.pc 0x0000000002c24634
    Event: 50.925 Thread 0x000000001be68000 Uncommon trap -34 fr.pc 0x0000000002c24634
    Event: 50.925 Thread 0x00000000200ec000 Uncommon trap -34 fr.pc 0x0000000002c24634

    Internal exceptions (10 events):
    Event: 46.484 Thread 0x000000001f9da800 Threw 0x000000076c79ffa0 at C:\jdk7u1_64p\jdk7u9\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
    Event: 46.580 Thread 0x000000001f9d8800 Threw 0x00000007659c4ab0 at C:\jdk7u1_64p\jdk7u9\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
    Event: 46.581 Thread 0x000000001f9d8800 Threw 0x00000007659ccb68 at C:\jdk7u1_64p\jdk7u9\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:1631
    Event: 46.581 Thread 0x000000001f9d8800 Threw 0x00000007659cd618 at C:\jdk7u1_64p\jdk7u9\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:1631
    Event: 47.398 Thread 0x000000001f9d8800 Threw 0x00000007621f7958 at C:\jdk7u1_64p\jdk7u9\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
    Event: 47.669 Thread 0x000000001fce3000 Threw 0x0000000758f945a0 at C:\jdk7u1_64p\jdk7u9\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
    Event: 49.268 Thread 0x000000001fce0800 Threw 0x0000000759eb4718 at C:\jdk7u1_64p\jdk7u9\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
    Event: 49.269 Thread 0x000000001fce0800 Threw 0x0000000759eb9078 at C:\jdk7u1_64p\jdk7u9\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
    Event: 49.269 Thread 0x000000001fce0800 Threw 0x0000000759ec2a18 at C:\jdk7u1_64p\jdk7u9\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
    Event: 50.918 Thread 0x000000001be65800 Threw 0x0000000774610150 at C:\jdk7u1_64p\jdk7u9\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166

    Events (10 events):
    Event: 50.924 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
    Event: 50.925 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
    Event: 50.925 Thread 0x000000001be68000 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x0000000002c24634 sp=0x000000002395e3f0
    Event: 50.925 Thread 0x000000001be68000 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x00000000029b9164 sp=0x000000002395e3a0 mode 2
    Event: 50.925 Thread 0x00000000200ec000 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x0000000002c24634 sp=0x000000002768e990
    Event: 50.925 Thread 0x00000000200ec000 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x00000000029b9164 sp=0x000000002768e940 mode 2
    Event: 51.304 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
    Event: 51.304 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
    Event: 51.304 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
    Event: 51.305 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done



    VM Arguments:
    jvm_args: -Xms1024m -Xmx8192m -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit 
    java_command: com.fr.start.Designer
    Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

    Environment Variables:
    JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45;
    PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows7Master;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45;/bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45;/jre/bin
    USERNAME=Administrator
    OS=Windows_NT
    PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=AMD64 Family 16 Model 4 Stepping 3, AuthenticAMD



    ---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

    OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7601 Service Pack 1

    CPU:total 4 (4 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 16 model 4 stepping 3, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, popcnt, mmxext, 3dnowpref, lzcnt, sse4a, tsc, tscinvbit, tscinv

    Memory: 4k page, physical 8387768k(5447484k free), swap 16773684k(11257520k free)

    vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.5-b02) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.7.0_09-b05), built on Sep 24 2012 21:45:04 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1600

    time: Wed Aug 28 19:01:43 2013
    elapsed time: 51 seconds
```

Comment: it maybe NIO write problem, some bytes didn't write to disk at all. but sometimes it writes correct, and sometimes it didn't work.

Comment: An NIO write problem is not an NIO read problem, and neither of them should cause JVM crashes.

Comment: the file length is 10, when i read postion 11 and use READONLY  `buffer = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, start , NIOConstant.PAGE_SIZE);` it cause crash

Answer (score 0):

Could it be due to [this bug](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/exception_access.xml)?

I see a number of answers stating that reinstalling the JVM often fixes the issue.

And [here's another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140030/possible-causes-of-java-vm-exception-access-violation) asking something similar.

Comment: @user2806176 'It' being what? Turning off UAC? Reinstalling? Upgrading?