# Effects of Fatal Error - crash happened in native code

Tags: java, java-native-interface, fatal-error

What are the effects happened for these types of error?

```
A fatal error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment.
The crash happened outside the java virtual machine in native code.
```

Comment: Maybe you'll find your answer in looking on the forum first ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140030/possible-causes-of-java-vm-exception-access-violation

Answer (score 2):

The JVM itself stops running. The JVM is a program (written in C++ in several cases) that runs your Java code. So your program will stop running. And it will stop in an uncontrolled manner: the JVM will (probably) not do any of its normal shut-down sequence, such as running shut-down hooks.

Answer (score 1):

The effect is that the JVM crashes, exits, stops, dies, finishes ...

It does this abruptly, and the JVM gets no chance to execute any application-specific shutdown hooks to tidy things up.  If the application was in the middle of writing a file, or something like that, that file not get written completely.

A JVM crash like this is typically *caused* by some application provided native code doing something that triggers a hardware exception (e.g. a "segmentation fault").  It is also possible that it is due to a bug in Java itself.