# error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

Tags: java, jasper-reports, fatal-error, access-violation

I'am trying to create a jasperReport but When I use this code:

```
JasperFillManager.fillReport(relJasper, parametros);
```

the system show error:

```
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000752dcf6a, pid=7736, tid=5252
#
# JRE version: 7.0_21-b11
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.21-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0xfcf6a]
```

Please help me!

Comment: Does it do this every time?  What are your machine specs?  Have you Googled around a bit to see what that `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION` means?

Comment: This could be a bug between jasper with the specific Java version. Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140030/possible-causes-of-java-vm-exception-access-violation gives you some tips. I would try a newer Java Version or given the process more memory.

Comment: Thanks guys, it's resolved, change  jasper version and configure tomcat memory.