# Failed to write core dump, Problematic frame: V JVM.dll

Tags: java, c, jvm, java-native-interface

I have the following crash on Windows 7 x86 machine, JDK7u51.
notice that the same code working on Windows 7 x64 bit.
Do you have any advice here?

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

> EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6744ebc5, pid=1832,
>   tid=1972
>
> JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_51-b13) (build
>   1.7.0_51-b13) Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 ) Problematic frame: V  [jvm.dll+0x7ebc5]
>
> Internal exceptions (10 events):
>   Event: 1.791 Thread 0x04044800 Threw 0x23e52550 at C:\re\jdk7u51\527\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
>   Event: 8.011 Thread 0x05b05400 Threw 0x24135170 at C:\re\jdk7u51\527\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\interpreterRuntime.cpp:347
>   Event: 8.012 Thread 0x05b05400 Threw 0x24135778 at C:\re\jdk7u51\527\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
>   Event: 16.067 Thread 0x05b05400 Threw 0x2413d158 at C:\re\jdk7u51\527\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
>   Event: 16.068 Thread 0x05b05400 Threw 0x24423608 at C:\re\jdk7u51\527\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
>   Event: 16.069 Thread 0x05b05400 Threw 0x24429018 at C:\re\jdk7u51\527\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
>   Event: 16.073 Thread 0x05b05400 Threw 0x2442f3d8 at C:\re\jdk7u51\527\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
>   Event: 16.082 Thread 0x05b05400 Threw 0x2444f538 at C:\re\jdk7u51\527\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
>   Event: 16.091 Thread 0x05b05400 Threw 0x24468d10 at C:\re\jdk7u51\527\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
>   Event: 16.098 Thread 0x05b05400 Threw 0x244827a0 at C:\re\jdk7u51\527\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244

I was trying to update the JDK to 8.161 but I got the same crash as follows:

## JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_161-b12) (build 1.8.0_161-b12)

## Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.161-b12 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )

## Problematic frame:

## V  [jvm.dll+0x96525]

So It is still not solved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible causes of Java VM EXCEPTION\_ACCESS\_VIOLATION?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140030/possible-causes-of-java-vm-exception-access-violation)

Comment: *"Do you have any advice here?"* - Yes, update the JVM. JDK 7u51 is a way too old and is no longer supported.

Comment: I have updated the JDK to 8.161 and still crash.

Comment: Is there full `hs_err_pid.log`?

Comment: yes i have hs_err_pid.log, but how I can upload it as it is too long to be post in a comment.

Comment: V  [jvm.dll+0x93b25]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1b9ef6]
V  [jvm.dll+0x18411b]
V  [jvm.dll+0x183521]
V  [jvm.dll+0x183937]
V  [jvm.dll+0x183b32]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1c3be6]
C  [msvcr100.dll+0x10fac]
C  [msvcr100.dll+0x110b1]
C  [kernel32.dll+0x53c45]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x637f5]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x637c8]
VM_Operation (0x1751f2f0): GenCollectForAllocation, mode: safepoint, requested by thread 0x15e0fc00

Comment: I think it is a Crash During Garbage Collection, Am I right? if yes, how to deal with it.