# Java Fatal error while loading modded minecraft

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am running the following and keep getting this error when trying to run Minecraft. I am told that this is a java error, not a Minecraft error but I have no idea what it means.

I am running Windows 10, 64-bit
24 GB ram (10 alotted to Minecraft)
Radeon 7970 graphics card (drivers up to date)
Intel 3570k CPU

The crash report can be found here (hs_err_pid7804.log): https://paste.ee/p/TfNwb

The minecraft error log itself is here:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffdfdd22c3a, pid=7804, tid=0x00000000000042dc
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_171-b11) (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.171-b11 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ig7icd64.dll+0x22c3a]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# E:\Program Files\Minecraft\MultiMC\instances\Sevtech\minecraft\hs_err_pid7804.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
```

Java bug reporting URL is down for maintenance.

My suspect is the Immersive Railroading mod. I works perfectly fine with a small number of mods but with as many as I have, it seems to cause a Java crash, not a Minecraft crash.

Their github is here: https://github.com/cam72cam/ImmersiveRailroading
Removing Immersive Railroading results in being able to play the game.

NOTE: The crash specifically happens when creating a new world. I can load the Minecraft Main Screen just fine.

I am using these java arguments:

-XX:+UseG1GC -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=2147483646 -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=42M -Dforge.forceNoStencil=true

Minimum memory allocation: 1024MB

Maximum memory allocation: 10480 MB

Permgen: 512MB

Can someone help me determine what the issue is? I kept a close eye on my ram usage and it doesn't get maxxed out. I ran memory tests and the sticks are fine with no memory leaks from drivers (less than 4gb being used in Windows when idle).

Comment: Might help a little: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140030/possible-causes-of-java-vm-exception-access-violation

Comment: The only thing there I found that could be relevant is related to garbage collection. How would I know if it was running at the time of the crash?

Comment: To be honest, I don't think it was the JVM's fault based on this line: "_The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in **native** code_". When looking at the full error log it _appears_ to me (and I am by no means versed in reading `hs_err` logs) that the issue is related to OpenGL (either OpenGL itself or Java code than invokes OpenGL). I'm sorry to say that I have no idea how to debug this. I'm competent at debugging Java code but when it comes to the JVM and/or GC I have no experience. Though based on the Java stack frames I would agree that _Immersive Railroading_ is responsible.