# Omnet++ (Eclipse IDE?) crashes when running INET projects - EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION in opplibs.dll

Tags: c++, eclipse, omnet++, inet

Currently working with Omnet++ and INET on my bachelors thesis. I managed to work just fine, however since a few weeks my Omnet IDE starts crashing either when trying to run a simulation, or just after a few minutes when opening normally.

I've already reinstalled the entire Omnet++ and Inet package, as if it were entirely new. After this reinstall, the IDE doesn't seem to crash by itself anymore, and I'm able to run non INET simulations. However, still, after trying to run a INET simulation the program crashes immediatly.

Here's an error similar to all the ones I get, usually with just few differences:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006848962e, pid=14676, tid=0x0000000000001f98
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_102-b14) (build 1.8.0_102-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.102-b14 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [opplibs.dll+0xc962e]
#
```

opplibs.dll is in every single one of these error messages. But even a reinstalled opplibs has not fixed the issue. I'm really at a wits end and need pointers. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out the mistake in this part.

Inside my .ini file, I was calling
    `tkenv-plugin-path = ../../../etc/plugins` , however due to a change in my file structure that path was no longer correct. This was throwing the EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION without any further error message.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this project have its repository on github - https://github.com/omnetpp/omnetpp
so it's the best place to ask for it. Simply go to "Issues" bookmark and search for your issue or create new one.
You can also look there for similiar issues: [Possible causes of Java VM EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140030/possible-causes-of-java-vm-exception-access-violation)