# Getting "A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:" when trying to run JavaFX code

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, javafx, fatal-error

I am getting this error:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ff90fdfed10, pid=4140, tid=3980

 JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (14.0.2+12) (build 14.0.2+12-46)
 Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (14.0.2+12-46, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
 Problematic frame:
 C  0x00007ff90fdfed10

 No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

 An error report file with more information is saved as:
 C:\Users\Vladimir\eclipse-workspace\Lol1\hs_err_pid4140.log

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
 The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
 See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

This only happens when I try to run JavaFX code. The JavaFX library itself is installed correctly. I've tried using different JDKS but nothing works (openjdk 15 on IntelliJ). I have updated,reinstalled java multiple times to no avail. I've also tried both eclipse and IntelliJ and they both get the same errors. The issue has nothing to do with the code written itself because it happens even when creating a new JavaFX project and trying to run the default blank window. The window itself appears for less than a second, disappears and then I get the error. I am pretty desperate at this point, any help is appreciated.

Edit: I am going to link the whole error log (From IntelliJ) in pastebin because I'm honestly completely lost

https://pastebin.com/FN3CqGr4

Comment: Kindly read the 2 links below:

https://java.com/en/download/help/exception_access.html


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140030/possible-causes-of-java-vm-exception-access-violation


It gave you an error file, open it and see what it says, it might give you information on how to fix it.    C:\Users\Vladimir\eclipse-workspace\Lol1\hs_err_pid4140.log

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I literally just updated windows and it fixed itself.. lol