# How to debug java EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION error

Tags: java, debugging, jenkins, logging, vdi

I have `java` test file, which keeps failing randomly in the `jenkins` CI TEST stage with the below error:

```
22:22:54  # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
22:22:54  #
22:22:54  #  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000001be683cf4bd, pid=428, tid=13744
22:22:54  #
22:22:54  # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (11.0.5+10) (build 11.0.5+10-LTS)
22:22:54  # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.5+10-LTS, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
22:22:54  # Problematic frame:
22:22:54  # J 21693 c2 org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertyName.defaultElementEquals(Lorg/springframework/boot/context/properties/source/ConfigurationPropertyName$Elements;Lorg/springframework/boot/context/properties/source/ConfigurationPropertyName$Elements;I)Z (436 bytes) @ 0x000001be683cf4bd [0x000001be683cf460+0x000000000000005d]
```

Few notes:

1. It happens only on `jenkins` agents, and not on my personal `VDI`, so it might be related to something with the code and resource allocation...
2. Java version is the same on my `VDI` and `jenkins` agent
3. As I said, it does passes once per 5 runs, but it makes life and delivery really tuff...
4. It happens every time on the same component tests, so clearly something is wrong there...

I want to start debug the issue by adding more `debug` info to the `file`, so maybe I'll get more information from the `jenkins`, but I don't know where to start.

The `file` has 434 lines of code, but I don't have a clue on which line I should start to add more info.
unfortunately, I can't share it due to security issue, but I was wonder if you can give me tips on how to start or where/what to search

Comment: https://ugetfix.com/ask/how-to-fix-exception-access-violation-error-on-windows-10/

Comment: Do a memtest on your server.

Comment: I'm not sure the organization will allow me to use memtest on the `jenkins` agent... @LMC per the thread, this happens constantly, and it doesn't explain how come after few tries, the CI does pass.

Comment: I really think it's some HW, but I need to understand first why it happens in this specific test and not with the others

Comment: @arielma Is „_`java` test file_“ a JUnit test class? If yes, can you share the test method that fails and the declaration/initialization and further usage of non-local variables it uses? Is the output from the Jenkins build's Console Output? There's `JRE version` in the message. Is this the active JRE on the OS Jenkins is running on? What's under _Manage Jenkins_ → _Global Tool Configuration_ → _JDK_?

Comment: Yes the output is from Jenkins console. One more info I've found in the log: `8  Gradle suite > Gradle test > XXX_setup.server.controller.LocationControllerComponentTest STANDARD_OUT
12:46:58      Aug 18,12:46:57.783 INFO Trying to load drivers to listener from test class: XXX_setup.server.controller.LocationControllerComponentTest
12:46:58  #`